# Existe uma tabela em que a coluna se chama DATE e ao tentar selecionar essa coluna o oracle não deixa. Alguém tem uma ideia do que fazer?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

```
SELECT A.DATE FROM TESTE A;
```

> ORA-01747: especificação inválida para usuário.tabela.coluna,
> tabela.coluna ou de coluna
> 01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

Depois eu tentei rodar olhando a tabela DUAL mas também não funcionou.

```
SELECT DATE FROM DUAL;
```

> ORA-00936: expressão não encontrada
> 00936. 00000 -  "missing expression"

Eu gostaria de ver se alguém tem uma alternativa sem ser alterar a nomenclatura do campo, caso contrário eu vou precisar falar com o dba.

Desde já agradeço a todos.

Comment: Existe uma coluna DATE na tabela TESTE ? Na DUAL não existe .... https://www.devmedia.com.br/tabela-dual-do-oracle/17218 DATE não é um bom nome para coluna , crie algo como  DATE_TEST ...

Answer (score -1):

seria select sysdate from dual ;
para seu problema
já no caso desse select ai ("SELECT A.DATE FROM TESTE A;") não precisa colocar o alias e pode seguir normal colocando select colunaDeData from tabela;

caso não funcione , tenta utilizar o Date de uma forma com to_char(SYSDATE,'dd/mm/yyyy') para ele pegar o dia desse campo

E tbm tenta fazer sempre colunas que não utilizam palavras reservadas do sistema em si por exemplo fazer uma coluna de saida e utilizar o OUT como o nome da coluna;

Usa o

```sql
to_char(SYSDATE,'dd/mm/yyyy')
```

para resovler a questão.

se quiser ver a data utiliza

```sql
select sysdate from dual;
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).